# Using ONLY CSS and HTML to set "required" attribute for texarea if radio button is checked

Tags: html, css

I need to add the attribute ":required" on a textarea if a radio button is checked; I cannot use javascript, only css and html, is it possible?

practically if the radio button is checked the text area have to be filled, otherwise it can be empty
thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it's possible without JS. HTML/CSS do not have such if/else capabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments:

> it's not possible without JS. HTML/CSS do not have such if/else capabilities

---

The only thing I could come up with, without using JS

is to **eventually** use two textareas and some CSS adjacent selectors `~`, and have the `hidden` required textarea already prefilled with a value:

```css
[name='agree']:checked ~ [name='text_req'] { display: inline-block; }
[name='agree']:checked ~ [name='text']     { display: none; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="agree" id="agree" type="checkbox"><label for="agree">I do</label>
  <br>
  <textarea name="text" placeholder="Explain why"></textarea>
  <textarea name="text_req" class="hide" required hidden>You must explain why</textarea>
  <br>
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

which is absolutely **not elegant**, since the user has to first clear the *prefilled* text value in order to enter his own; and two textareas are being submitted.

## Using JavaScript

Using just a bit of JavaScript to toggle the `required` property:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('[name=text]');
document.querySelector('[name=agree]').addEventListener('change', function() {
  textarea.required = this.checked;
  textarea.placeholder = this.checked ? "Must Explain why" : "Explain why";
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label><input name="agree" type="checkbox">I do</label><br>
  <textarea name="text" placeholder="Explain why"></textarea><br>
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks Roko....it seems that there is not a possible way....but your suggestion gave me an idea for a work around.

Answer (score 1):

Css controls only the styles not the validation so you cannot validate your form with the css.

Comment: To apply your styles for each one of them like a background color,... etc

Answer (score 0):

It's already been pointed out that you **should not** use CSS for validation. That said, you can effectively disable the textarea using `pointer-events: none`. Check this out:

```css
/* disable the textarea by default */
[name='text'] {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
/* enable it when input is checked */
[name='agree']:checked ~ [name='text'] {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="agree" id="agree" type="checkbox"><label for="agree">I do</label>
  <br>
  <textarea name="text" placeholder="Explain why"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

That said, don't use this snippet. Use JS.